# how do you convert matrix to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

x

```
  [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] List,5 List,5
[2,] List,5 List,5
[3,] List,5 List,5
[4,] List,5 List,5
[5,] List,5 List,5
[6,] List,5 List,5
```

How would I convert this to a data frame?

when I do this:

```
head(x[1,1],2)
[[1]]

               DATE_TIME                                                     SITE RESPONSE_TIME AVAIL_PERCENT AGENT
1   2013-MAY-24 05:09 PM  Keynote Business 40 TxP - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]             -             - 45693
2   2013-MAY-24 05:24 PM  Keynote Business 40 TxP - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]             -             - 45693
3   2013-MAY-24 05:39 PM  Keynote Business 40 TxP - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]             -             - 45693
4   2013-MAY-24 05:54 PM  Keynote Business 40 TxP - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]             -             - 45693
5   2013-MAY-24 06:09 PM  Keynote Business 40 TxP - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]             -             - 45693
```

Comment: That looks strange ... of what type are the elements? Depending on that, you may just be able to use `as.data.frame`.

Comment: that does not work, it gives me one huge data frame with one column. I need to have 5 columns.

Comment: can you use `dput()` or give us a reproducible example of constructing this object ... ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, since there is so much data, I just printed out the head(x[1,1]),4) to give you an idea.

Comment: so just wrap `dput()` around `head()` and give us that

Comment: So, it's a list of matrices? A multidimensional array?Does `as.data.frame(x[[1]])` work?

Comment: It looks like you have a matrix of lists, possibly created by calling `as.matrix` on a list.

Comment: @Jason Morgan, as.data.frame(x[[1]]) worked when the matrix was two dimensional as above. I am doing the same to the following matrix, not working this time:     [,1]  
[1,] List,5
[2,] List,5
[3,] List,5
[4,] List,5
[5,] List,5
[6,] List,5
[7,] List,5
[8,] List,5

Comment: @user1471980 You should really give us an idea of the structure of your data; i.e., `str(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to address is whether the location in that matrix of lists has any meaning. If you only want to "flatten" it out", you could just do this:

```
 # Not workig : out <- do.call( as.data.frame, c(x) )
 # Then try:

out <- do.call( rbind, as.list(x) )
```

If you want a record of the locations you will need to use an approach that labels the output, perhaps with `apply` or by processing one matrix column at a time.

Comment: that did not work. what if my matrix looks like this:     [,1]  
[1,] List,5
[2,] List,5
[3,] List,5
[4,] List,5
[5,] List,5
[6,] List,5
[7,] List,5
[8,] List,5

Comment: Better would be to post the output of dbut, but I did test the new approach on a two column dataframe that I made into a 3 x 3 matrix with: `mdat <- matrix( list(dat), 3,3)`.